# Oracle XMLQUERY - delete all empty nodes under root

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a query:

```
  SELECT  DELETEXML(xmltype('<docGetResponse>
                            <histories>
                              <history>
                                <history/>
                              </history>
                            </histories>
                            <validations/>
                          </docGetResponse>'), '/docGetResponse/*[not(node())]')

  FROM    dual;
```

MY goal is to remove ALL EMPTY nodes under docGetResponse. In that case, from above xml should remain

```
<docGetResponse></docGetResponse>
```

OR

```
<docGetResponse/>
```

But query gives me error:
ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Oracle version? Query runs for me fine in 11.2.0.4 returning `<docGetResponse><histories><history><history/></history></histories></docGetResponse>`

Comment: ver: 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: Works for me in 12.2.0.1.0 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have some internal error.
2) DELETEXML is depracated sql function and it should be repalced with xmlquery.
3) Correct verison of xquery is `'/docGetResponse/*[not(.//text())]'`

```
  select xmlquery('copy $doc := . 
                modify delete nodes $doc/docGetResponse/*[not(.//text())] 
                return $doc' 
         passing xmltype('<docGetResponse>
                            <histories>
                              <history>
                                <history/>
                              </history>
                            </histories>
                            <validations/>                            
                            <xxx>
                              <a><b><c>av</c></b></a>
                            </xxx>
                          </docGetResponse>') returning content) from  dual;
```

Comment: Works perfectly but... only on oracle 11g :l
on oracle 12c error comes up